# Generating dates for unique combination of data

Tags: python, python-3.7

relatively new to Python. I'm trying to generate a date column for each unique combination of data in my dataframe. For instance, in this example I just want 3 days of data for each row -

Input:

```
  a      |      b      |      c      |      d     
  dogs          15           brown         30
  cats          24           black         43
```

Ideal output:

```
date      |     a      |      b      |      c      |      d     
day 1           dogs          15           brown         30
day 2           dogs          15           brown         30
day 3           dogs          15           brown         30
day 1           dogs          24           black         43
day 2           dogs          24           black         43
day 3           dogs          24           black         43
```

In my actual dataset, I need roughly 2 years of data per row, but ideally that's a variable that I can input somewhere in case someday I wanted 4/5 years of data. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you please update the question to show what you’ve tried so far and where you’ve gotten stuck?

Comment: Additionally, what determines the number of days to populate for each unique row?

Comment: Are you just trying to generate unique identifiers or do you want to generate actual dates.

Comment: I'm currently trying to google the expand_grid in python way, in R I'd probably just create a sequence of days out to x = 365*2 days where 2 = number of years using seq() and use expand_grid to generate days for each of those rows, not sure if there's a more efficient way in Python or an alternative method?

Comment: @RufusVS - just trying to generate actual dates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this perhaps:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([
  ["dogs", 15, "brown", 30],
  ["cats", 24, "black", 43]
], columns=["a", "b", "c", "d"]
)

# Repeat each row 3 times
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]

# Create a new column called date, as a list comprehension containing f-strings
df["date"] = [f"day {i}" for i in range(1, 4)] * 2

# Make the new date column into the dataframe index
df = df.set_index('date')

# Show the results
print(df)
```

Returning:

```
          a   b      c   d
date                      
day 1  dogs  15  brown  30
day 2  dogs  15  brown  30
day 3  dogs  15  brown  30
day 1  cats  24  black  43
day 2  cats  24  black  43
day 3  cats  24  black  43
```

Comment: This does do what I need! Would you mind explaining what the code is doing?

Comment: My pleasure. 1 second, and I will add some comments to the code.

Comment: Damn I thought it was me / deleteed the comment but no luck, same error - I get the error "Length of values does not match length of index"

Comment: Did you multiply your list by the number of unique original rows ? in the example dataframe the number to multiply by is 2

Comment: Also thanks for the comments in the code! One of my questions was what defines i? but maybe me not understanding is part of that error, my actual dataset was expanded to a 5x243 df after applying the index repeat, so I changed that second line to df["date"] = [f"day {i}" for i in range(1, 5)] * 243

Comment: ah, yes - I multiplied it by the repeated number of rows! So I'll try the unique number rows

Comment: shoot, no luck - same error, tried df["date"] = [f"day {i}" for i in range(1, 5)] * 81

Comment: I recommend you to place a middle step for better control: before going to your complete df, try a smaller subset of perhaps 10 or 20 rows. if that works, then gradually scale up so the error is easier to detect.

Comment: sweet - thanks for that, got it working! (didn't realize the range was not exclusive of the last value). Quick question, do you know if instead of adding an iterative string, I can generate a list of real dates? i.e 03/31/2020, 04/01/2020 etc.

Comment: I am happy it worked out. To generate a list of real dates, @Joran Beasley gave a really good answer, so I will point to his reply for this.

Comment: It is a pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

```
num_days = len(combinations_thing)
pandas.date_range('2020-07-19',freq="1d",periods=num_days)
```

i guess probably does what you want, the easiest... but its really hard to understand what you are actually asking from your problem statement.